# Спрятать/Показать текст — оптимизация существующего кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите оптимизировать код, он выполняет функционал показа/сокрытия дополнительной подписи к кнопке BUTTON. Подпись к кнопкам, при открытии страницы в браузере, отсутствует и появляется при фокусе (нажатии) на одну из кнопок, - на левую кнопку показывается подпись для левой кнопки при этом, если правая кнопка была ранее в фокусе, подпись прячется для правой кнопки, и наоборот.
Мне кажется, что это можно привести в более изящный вид, ведь я в этом не специалист, пока, и логику слепил по примерам :)

```
Роли исполняют:    

button[id=left]     — левая кнопка    
button[id=right]    — правая кнопка    
span[id=left]       — подпись левой кнопки   
span[id=right]      — подпись правой кнопки
```

JQuery-код

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// при открытии страницы прячем подпись для всех кнопок
    $("span[id=left]").hide();
    $("span[id=right]").hide();
// скрываем подпись если кнопка теряет фокус
  $("button").blur(function(){
    $("span[id=left]").hide();
    $("span[id=right]").hide();
  });
// если левая кнопка получила фокус, то выводим для нее подпись и прячем подпись для другой кнопки (#right)
  $("button[id=left]").focus(function(){
    $("span[id=left]").show();
    $("span[id=right]").hide();
  });
// если правая кнопка получила фокус, то выводим для нее подпись и прячем подпись для другой кнопки (#left)
  $("button[id=right]").focus(function(){
    $("span[id=right]").show();
    $("span[id=left]").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML-код

```
<div class="button">
    <span id="left" style="position: relative; top: 16px; right: 30px;" class="descr">Описание для левой кнопки</span>
    <button id="left" class="button">Левая кнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button id="right" class="button">Правая кнопка</button>
    <span id="right" style="position: relative; top: 16px; left: 30px;" class="descr">Описание для правой кнопки</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Атрибуты id не должны повторяться! Уберите их вообще или оставьте только уникальные. Код сократить можно так:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("span.descr").hide();
        $("button")
            .blur(function(){
                $("span.descr").hide();
            })
            .focus(function() {
                $("span.descr").hide();
                $(this).parent().find("span.descr").show();
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: будьте добры, как все же будет выглядеть строка кода вызывающая событие `show()` по идентификатору HTML-тэга, ведь селектор класса `(span.descr)` может использоваться и для других элементов, которые не будут затребованы. Это вроде решает метод `parent()`, но тогда он не позволит сделать следующее: например, я бы хотел нажать по кнопке с `<button id="right">` и показать подпись на странице везде, где встечается `<span id="rightspan">` (прошу простить если я неправильно понял работу вашего примера)

Comment: parent() - это поиск в родительском контейнере <div class="button"> из вашего примера. если нужно искать по всей странице, то нужно $('#'+$(this).id+'span').show()

Answer (score 0):

Используй селектор по id вместо тега с атрибутом.